# PHPWord - Select save location

Tags: php, file, save, phpword

I have implemented the PHPWord on my website to generate a template.
Everything works fine but there is only one detail. When my file is saved in the site that I choose, a copy is saved in the directory where my php script is located.

Example:
I click the generate button and select the desktop to save the file. okay
But in the directory where my php "generate.php" is located a copy of the generated file is saved.

```
--//I type the name of my file.
$nombrearchivo = 'MOP_Implementacion MW_'.$sitene.'_to_'.$sitefe.'_Raylex.docx';
```

I save my file

```
$templateWord->saveAs($nombrearchivo);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nombrearchivo.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
echo file_get_contents($nombrearchivo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the solution:
`unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file`